# Admod - Rendering Problems - Classes not instantiated

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to put Admob for android app in studio and then publish it on google play.

I have read that soon, google requires a very specific way of displaying banner.

I wonder if this form is correct and incidentally try to fix the bug that gives me.

The mobile works perfect, but not that get the error on android studio.

I put a picture to make it easier to find the error.

Hope you can help me, Thanks.

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwhtX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is from an old version of Admob (6.4.1), and is only an error when trying to render the AdView within your editor, it is not a runtime error.

Try using the new Admob SDK (the one from Google Play Services). It is much more likely to have this (editor  only) bug fixed.

Comment: @Whiliam Excuse me, but could be more accurate, not English and I'm starting in java. 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: See my update. Basically try with the Google Play Services version of the Admob SDK.